# Did Trump authorise a 2016 negative political ad against the Jewish elite?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, advertising

There is a negative political ad floating around that is alleged to be from the 2016 Trump campaign. Its content is the standard anti-globalist fare. The ad implies that Democrat presidential candidates are conspiring with a "global elite". The video singles out three examples of the "global elite", who happen to be Jews - [Trump’s latest ad slammed for targeting Jews, dogwhistle anti-Semitism](https://www.sbs.com.au/news/article/trumps-latest-ad-slammed-for-targeting-jews-dogwhistle-anti-semitism/yawdksohd).

Is Trump anti-Semitic and did he authorise this ad or is this fake news?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145035/discussion-on-question-by-gmatht-did-trump-authorise-a-2016-negative-political-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Discussion about the interpretation of the ad aside, I was able to find out [that](https://www.businessinsider.com/donald-trump-closing-argument-ad-2016-11) this was "$4 million" piece, but I'm not sure what that means exactly: probably not just the production value, but how much it cost to place it, I'd guess. (Yeah, according to CNN, $4 million [was](https://money.cnn.com/2016/11/04/media/donald-trump-two-minute-ads/) the TV slot cost, not the production cost.)

Anyhow, BI says

> Titled “Donald Trump’s Argument for America,” the ad was set to air in major markets in battleground states. The Trump campaign said it would also air during NFL, NCAA, and NASCAR programming.
>
> "This is Mr. Trump's positive closing message to American voters, and it comes at a time when Secretary Clinton has abandoned any positive message of her own,” said Jason Miller, senior communications adviser.

CNN adds that the clip's time was bit unusual:

> TV ads are usually 30 seconds long, so Trump is trying to stand out by buying longer blocks of time and placing the ads during Saturday college football games, Sunday NFL games, and tentpole shows like "The Voice."
>
> The idea is that the uncommonly long ads will stand out from the noise. [...]
>
> Miller said the "positive closing message" ad would air in Florida, Pennsylvania, Nevada, Ohio, Michigan, Colorado, Iowa, North Carolina, and New Mexico during news, prime time shows and sportscasts.
>
> It will also air on NASCAR broadcasts, NBC's "The Voice," and across cable news.

RealClearPolitics [also](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/video/2016/11/04/ad_donald_trumps_argument_for_america.html) confirms list of states where the Trump 2-minute ad was intended to run.

And according to a Nov 8, 2016 [article](https://swarajyamag.com/insta/in-his-tv-ad-trumps-last-push), close to 7 million views on YouTube of the clip were garnered before that date. (The clip has 8.7 million views on YT now.)

Regarding the content of the ad, the Jerusalem Post [notes](https://www.jpost.com/diaspora/latest-trump-ad-contains-prominent-jews-in-positions-of-global-power-471874) that the Trump campaign then rejected accusations of elements of anti-semitism in the ad, through the voices of two individuals the newspaper describes as [his] "top Jewish surrogate[s]": Jason Greenblatt and David Friedman. (I'm guessing the latter refers to [David M. Friedman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_M._Friedman), because Wikipedia mentions that during that 2016 presidential campaign, he was "co-chairing Trump's Israel Advisory Committee along with [Jason D. Greenblatt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Greenblatt), an executive vice president for The Trump Organization.") Friedman in particular focused on rejecting the Jewish relevance of Soros: "Mr. Soros, whose name is not recognizably Jewish and who has done nothing to positively identify with the Jewish people [...]" followed by further complaints about Soros' stance on Israel.